# AWS Athena, Erro when Len of String

Tags: amazon-athena

I tried to show the len of one string..

```
SELECT length(fieldA) FROM "data_prod"."myscore" limit 10;
```

but I receive that error

Your query has the following error(s):

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Unexpected parameters (bigint) for function length. Expected: length(varchar(x)) , length(char(x)) , length(varbinary)

This query ran against the "raw_public_data_prod" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 92f6401b-108a-4671-951e-3a8e882f3b20.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJMN5.png)

Comment: Are you trying to calculate length of an integer? What is the exact value stored in fieldA ? Have you tried casting it to a varchar data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT length(cast(fieldA as varchar)) FROM "data_prod"."myscore" limit 10;
```

`length` function doesn't work for `bigint` data type. So you have to cast it as `varchar` to do so.